# Building a JSON-LD product Schema dynamically with if statements

Tags: json

I am trying to complete some product schema in JSON-LD but some strings need to be output dynamically. I include some sample markup below:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var el = document.createElement('script');
  el.type = 'application/ld+json';
  el.text = JSON.stringify( {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "ProductName",
    "aggregateRating": {
      "@type": "AggregateRating",
      "worstRating": "1",
      "bestRating": "5",
      "ratingValue": "ProductRatingValue",
      "reviewCount": "ProductReviewCount"
    },
  });
  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(el);
});
```

If a product contains no reviews, the `ratingValue` and `reviewCount` output `0` which causes the validator to err with 'failed to normalise ratings'.

Is there a JSON compatible way to only output `ratingValue` and `reviewCount` based on an if statement? I have looked over quite a bit documentation and haven't come across how this can be achieved syntactically although I suspect it is surely possible...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the JSON fully **before** you stringify it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var el = document.createElement('script');
  el.type = 'application/ld+json';
  var jsonLd = {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "ProductName",
    "aggregateRating": {
      "@type": "AggregateRating",
      "ratingValue": "ProductRatingValue",
      "reviewCount": "ProductReviewCount"
    }
  };
  if (yourRatingValue > 0) { jsonLd.ratingValue = yourRatingValue; }
  if (yourReviewCount > 0) { jsonLd.reviewCount = yourReviewCount; }
  el.text = JSON.stringify(jsonLd);

  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(el);
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was seeking and helped me to build the JSON dynamically! Thanks :)